# How to modify excel file using PHPExcel in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, phpexcel

In my project I use symfony2 PHPExcel wrapper https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle

With the example from the link above I can create new excel files. However this file has no style or markup at all. So I created a excel template where I want to input some data.

I know how to load an excel file:

```
$excelObj = $this->get('xls.load_xls2007')
                 ->load($this->get('kernel')
                 ->getRootDir() . '/../web/excel-template.xlsx');

//custom modifications on excel file
```

Now I need to create a response. But in the doc of ExcelBundle there is no information on how to do that. They just show how response work for a excel file that is created by code.

I tried:

```
 $excelService->setExcelObj($excelObj);
 $response = $excelService->getResponse();
 //the rest is equal to the code in the doc
```

but it gives me a blank excel document.

Any ideas how to make a response with a loaded excel file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by

```
// Read the file
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

    // Change the file
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
                ->setCellValue('B1', 'World!');

    // Write the file
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
    $objWriter->save($fileName);
```

if you dont understand please comment..

Answer (score 0):

I would save the file to disk and redirect the user to the on-disk version personally.  This will allow several things

- Your web server to serve files instead of PHP, a good thing from a performance and memory usage standpoint.
- Decouple your architecture a bit to allow for future changes such as moving the creation and loading of Excel files to asynchronous operations.
- The ability to use http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile (There is an Apache module also).
- The user can re-download the file or pause and resume download without recreating it.

To do this you will want to

- Save the file to a web accessible temp directory after its created
- Redirect the user to that file location
- Create a cron or some other job that deletes older files in the temp directory.

The tempfile api (http://us2.php.net/tmpfile) might be useful here.

Comment: I don't know how this can solve my problem. I just want to know the line of code to save and respond a xml file

Answer (score 0):

the new version 2.* of PHPExcelbundle could help you.

Is now possible:

```
//read
$phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject('file.xls');
$phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
  ->setCellValue( 'C6', 'some text' )
  ->setCellValue( 'D6', 'some text2' );
$writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Excel5');
$writer->save('file.xls');
// or 
$response = $this->get('phpexcel')->createStreamedResponse($writer);
```